# Sql select including top 1 with ties + limit rows

Tags: sql-server

My code looks like the below. it is working perfectly but the rows are too many and I want to limit the results in sql with LIMIT 0, 20

```
select top 1 with ties c.cid, c.cname, c.cmobile, c.cdate, c.email, h.sdate 
From Customers c
LEFT JOIN history h
on c.cid=h.cid 
order by row_number() over (partition by c.cname order by h.sdate desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Second TOP statement, using #temp table.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES c.cid, c.cname, c.cmobile, c.cdate, c.email, h.sdate 
INTO #temp
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN history h
   ON c.cid=h.cid 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.cname ORDER BY h.sdate DESC)

SELECT TOP 20 cid, cname, cmobile, cdate, email, sdate 
FROM #temp
WHERE cid > '2000' AND cid < '3000'
ORDER BY cname ASC
```

Comment: I have added Where cid > '2000' and cid < '3000' in your statement and I've got the results what I needed. so your statement looks like that:

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES c.cid, c.cname, c.cmobile, c.cdate, c.email, h.sdate 
INTO #temp
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN history h
   ON c.cid=h.cid 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.cname ORDER BY h.sdate DESC)

SELECT  cid, cname, cmobile, cdate, email, sdate 
Where cid > '2000' and cid < '3000'
Order By cname ASC
FROM #temp

Comment: @Zlatko Do you mean to update my answer with WHERE clause?

Comment: Yes, I added Where cid > '2000' and cid < '3000' on the #temp table and I've got the records with cid between 2000 and 3000. this is what I wanted and with your suggestion it helped me to achieve it. now I can manipulate the digits. 
Thank you lad2025

Answer (score 0):

You can pass It to sub-query like this:

```
select top 20 *
from(
   select top 1 with ties c.cid, c.cname, c.cmobile, c.cdate, c.email, h.sdate 
   From Customers c
   LEFT JOIN history h
   on c.cid=h.cid 
   order by row_number() over (partition by c.cname order by h.sdate desc)
) x
```

Comment: your solution will work if I needed to select only top rows. in fact I needed to select few rows somewhere in the middle and I just found that it is very difficult to do it in sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

For Sql Server 2012 and later:

```
select c.cid, c.cname, c.cmobile, c.cdate, c.email, h.sdate 
From Customers c
LEFT JOIN history h
on c.cid=h.cid 
order by row_number() over (partition by c.cname order by h.sdate desc)
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: This is the best option and I think I need to migrate to sql server 2012. thanks M.Ali